# loading data into mysql, --secure-file-priv and local

Tags: mysql, macos, load, local

I am trying to load data, I have it in .csv and .txt files (loading from either or is fine), into a table. When I use "load data infile" with the correct path (I'm copying and pasting the path) I get the error:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Then I get this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv | NULL  |
+------------------+-------+
```

I am also trying to use load data local, but then I get the error:

> ERROR 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

I tried this, but the error still persists:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

I am new to using MySQL and am accessing it through Terminal on a mac.

I have read online about modifying the my.cnf file but I don't believe there is one on my mac.